# How can i query entries by a field that are within a matrix?

Tags: twig, octobercms, craftcms

Each entry has a matrix field with fields including start date, end date, location etc

I need to list and display only the entries after now.

I am able to filter them by

```
{% set queryEntries = craft.entries({
    section: ['events'],
}) %}

{% for entry in queryEntries.all() %}
    {% if entry.eventDetails.dateFrom|date("U")  > "now"|date("U") %}
        {{ entry.title }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This isn't great though as when the events list grows it won't be very performant and I have entries that I don't want.

Am I am able to filter the queryEntries by entry.eventDetails.dateFrom|date("U")  > "now"|date("U") ?

Comment: Twig is a templating language, so it is not meant for that. You should do this processing when you query your models collections at a controller level rather.

Comment: just do the logical part in your `PHP code section` and pass the variable to twig, you do not want to do logical things in twig.